# check time between messages sent from client to server application

Tags: python

I want my server to send the string "con-res 0xFE" to reset the server if it has been more than 4 seconds since a new message was sent by the client.

I have tried to puzzle around with time.time() but in the end I can't figure out how to register a time for each message it self.

Client:

```
  import socket

  # Create a UDP socket
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

  server_address = ('localhost', 12000)
  number_of_packages = 0;
     try:
     while True:
    message = input("Write something: ")

    # Send data
    sent = sock.sendto(message.encode(), server_address)
    number_of_packages +=1
    if (number_of_packages > 25):
        print("Too many packages - closing socket")
        socket.close()


    # Receive response
    data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print('client received: ', data.decode())
    if data.decode()=="con-res 0xFE":
        print("conn reset!")
        sent = sock.sendto("con-res 0xFFDDDDD".encode(), server_address)

 finally:
 sock.close()
```

My server:

```
       # Create a UDP socket
      sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

                # Bind the socket to the port
                server_address = ('localhost', 12000)
                sock.bind(server_address)
                count_message = 0
                while True:
                    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

                    #check 4 seconds since last message





                    if data:
                        start_time = time.time()
                        sent = sock.sendto("ok".encode(), address)
```

The above code incidents might be wrong as I had difficulties make sure it looked as code here on Stackoverflow. However the above code is working as it should.